# Cross domain cookie with two environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, web, server, cross-domain

Currently I am stuck with a little problem which I would like to solve as cleanly as possible.

I have two environments, a staging environment and a production environment. I'm using Ruby on Rails as a Framework.

Each environment consists of three servers communicating with each other. For an authentication functionality a cookie is being shared among these three servers. Now the problem arises between staging environment and production environment since both environments share the same domain:

```
sub1-staging.example.com
sub2-staging.example.com
sub3-staging.example.com

sub1.example.com
sub2.example.com
sub3.example.com
```

The cookie of the staging environment is also visible on the production environment. I guess that this is a common problem.

Are there any good solutions to this except deleting the cookies after finishing working in one environment or renaming the cookie depending on the environment?

Answer (score 0):

I am saying have single cookie for base domain and just ignore sub domain..though this approach has some flaws still ...

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_application_devise_session', domain: 'lvh.me'
```

you can visit http://excid3.com/blog/sharing-a-devise-user-session-across-subdomains-with-rails-3/